# How can I get my iterative algorithm to work?

Tags: java, algorithm, iteration

I'm writing an iterative algorithm using the formula  T<sub>n</sub> = T<sub>n - 1</sub> + T<sub>n - 3</sub>  resulting in the sequence
{ 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 15, 22, 32, 47, 69, 101 } etc. I'm not sure how to do this but this is what I have tried:

```
    public long calculate(long n) {

    if (n <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (n == 2){
        return 2;
    }
    int firstValue = 1;
    int secondValue = 1;
    int thirdValue;
    



    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        thirdValue = firstValue;
        firstValue += secondValue;
        secondValue = thirdValue;


    }

    return firstValue;
```

I think I have to use some kind of forthValue but not sure how to. Would appreciate some advice.

Comment: `n = (n - 1) + (n - 3)` isn't a sequence. It's a formula that can be reduced to `n = 4`.

Comment: But I wrote that it is a formula (...using the formula n = (n - 1) + (n - 3))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a JavaScript counterpart but you can surely focus on the algorithm. Your `forthValue` can be the `result` (`firstValue` + `thirdValue`) of each iteration and after **one iteration is complete**, we swap the values such that :-

**`thirdValue` becomes `secondValue`**

**`secondValue` becomes `firstValue`**

**`firstValue` becomes the `result`**

The following will work :-

```js
//n = n-1 + n-3

function calculate(n) {

    if (n <= 0) {
        return [0];
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        return [0,1];
    }
    if (n == 2){
        return [0,1,2];
    }
    
    let firstValue = 2
    let secondValue = 1
    let thirdValue = 0;
    let result = 0;
    

   const output = [0,1,2];
  
    for (let i = 3; i < n; i++) {
       result = firstValue + thirdValue;
       output.push(result);
       thirdValue = secondValue
       secondValue = firstValue
       firstValue = result;
    }
    return output
    }
    
    let result = calculate(15);
    console.log(result);
```

Another way if we are anyway going to have an `output` array could be using it to find the next value like so :-

```js
//n = n-1 + n-3

function calculate(n) {

    if (n <= 0) {
        return [0];
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        return [0,1];
    }
    if (n == 2){
        return [0,1,2];
    }
    
   
   const output = [0,1,2];
  
    for (let i = 3; i < n; i++) {
       output.push(output[i-3]+output[i-1]);
    }
    return output
    }
    
    let result = calculate(15);
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

for me it looks your formula like

```
n = 2n-4
```

but the numbers are not matching.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add variables like `forthValue` indefinitely - to solve this kind of issues you can use [recursion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/)

So this would look like this:

```
public class Test {

    public long calculate(long n) {
        if (n <= 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (n == 1) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (n == 2){
            return 2;
        }
        return calculate(n - 1) + calculate(n - 3);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test testClass = new Test();

        for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(testClass.calculate(i));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to write it as a recursive algorithm but for this one I want to write it as an iterative algorithm, but thank you  :)

Answer (score 0):

(n - 1) + (n - 3) -> 2n - 4 and is simple to implement as an iterative algorithm, but seeing your code I'm not sure that's what you had in mind.

```
public long calculate(long n) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum = 2 * sum - 4;
    }
    return sum;

}
```